# How would I take this derivative?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I am not really sure how I would take the following derivative:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left( F(r) \right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left( \int_{0}^{2 \pi} f(r,\theta) d\theta \right)$

Would it maybe just be:

$\frac{d}{dr}\left( F(r) \right)  = \left( \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{\partial f(r,\theta)}{\partial r} d\theta \right)$

Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. Because the boundaries of the integral do not depend on $r$, the derivative can be simply moved inside the integral.

If the bounds of integration did depend on $r$, extra terms from the boundaries would have to be included - look up "differentiation under the integral" if you are interested. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your suggestion is correct, but only subject to certain conditions which your function $f$ will probably meet in practice.

This is called *differentiation under the integral sign* ([link to Wikipedia](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC4QFjADahUKEwiV97DC6onJAhWHBBoKHetaCzw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FDifferentiation_under_the_integral_sign&usg=AFQjCNG79qbnKokju98jAiBVQCqcIZBMiQ&sig2=FHBDfKvCOiy4e8fCgga0lw&bvm=bv.107406026,d.d2s)).

The topic (by which I mean the question of "when is this interchange of symbols valid?") is covered in, among other books, Apostol's *Mathematical Analysis* (listed in the index) and Buck's *Advanced Calculus* (listed in the index under "Differentiation of functions defined by integrals").

I find [this](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDkQFjAEahUKEwiV97DC6onJAhWHBBoKHetaCzw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uconn.edu%2F~kconrad%2Fblurbs%2Fanalysis%2Fdiffunderint.pdf&usg=AFQjCNF_D_OYxMHerHgLVUUkBbDXzBeM2A&sig2=PhzHDjpKkvKYtGJDDxrJoA&bvm=bv.107406026,d.d2s) pdf by K. Conrad to be a good introduction to the actual use of the technique to solve problems, and is probably more in-depth than what you're looking for at the moment, but does have a precise statement of the relevant theorem towards the end.